# DataTable with Rails Failed to submit multiple pages items

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am using jquery datatable to view table data from the Backend in html for Rails App

[image]

When I select any record/row using checkbox to submit on back end let say from page 1, & checked few items on page 2 & hit confirm button.Items received at the back end is only the current page.

For example if checked items from page 2 & hit the confirm button , items submitted to back end is only from page 2 which was checked, & If checked items from page 1 & hit the confirm button, items submitted to backend is only from page 1 which was checked.

As Expected behavior I am trying to achieve is on submitting confirm , Data tables should transmitted checked items across the page, which is not currently happening.

Can Anyone help , Is this achievable by Data-tables or it is bug in library.
All suggestion are welcome.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:ruby], I have the tag removed.

Comment: @Hard Is confirm button action is an AJAX call?

Comment: No, It is not Ajax Call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@manivel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40152510/3549014) mentioned correctly, if you're using server-side processing, it's not possible.

With client-side processing, there are couple ways to do it.

#### SOLUTION 1: Submit form directly

The trick is to turn form elements from pages other than current into `<input type="hidden">` before submitting the form.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Handle form submission event
$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
   var form = this;

   // Encode a set of form elements from all pages as an array of names and values
   var params = table.$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();

   // Iterate over all form elements
   $.each(params, function(){
      // If element doesn't exist in DOM
      if(!$.contains(document, form[this.name])){
         // Create a hidden element
         $(form).append(
            $('<input>')
               .attr('type', 'hidden')
               .attr('name', this.name)
               .val(this.value)
         );
      }
   });
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/ak6v0gj2/) for code and demonstration.

#### SOLUTION 2: Submit form via Ajax

Another solution is to submit the form via Ajax.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Handle form submission event
$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
   // Prevent actual form submission
   e.preventDefault();

   // Serialize form data
   var data = table.$('input,select,textarea').serialize();

   // Submit form data via Ajax
   $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/jsonp/',
      data: data,
      success: function(data){
         console.log('Server response', data);
      }
   });
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/ma0gyy28/) for code and demonstration.

#### NOTES

Please note that both solutions will work in client-side processing mode only.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gyrocode.com , It's working now as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If it is server side pagination, it is not achievable.

## UPDATE

If it is client side pagination, you can append all the selected checkbox values in on submit jQuery action method and process it in server.

Comment: It is client side pagination , all record are render on client side on page load , If I checked 2 record on page 1 & 2 record on page 2 both the checked record remained until request is submitted to server.